# Grails Spring Security - Always redirect to specific page after login?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a grails application that is using the spring security plugin for authentication. If my session expires, and I click a link in the application it takes me to the login screen then tries to redirect to the page I was on previously.

I would like to configure spring security to always redirect to the home page instead of the last page the user clicked on. Is there a setting that controls this behavior?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Beyond setting the `defaultTargetUrl` you also need to tell Spring Security to **force the use** of that default target URL. Your `Config.groovy` should look something like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/home'
```

You can research further options using the Spring Security API documentation for the [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), should you need them.

**UPDATE:**
Later versions of the plugin use `grails.plugin` and not `grails.plugins`

Comment: I see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14284211/2051952) also uses `successHandler.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` setting, but do we need that? The property value in the bean [is set from `alwaysUseDefault`](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/37115147db8e71904fe7bc36b8aa1a311ef83f23/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy#L1117)

Comment: It's possible that it was consolidated over recent versions. I haven't looked but it's quite possible. I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Looks like it although I also see [1.x version also uses the same way](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/1.x/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy#L1008) the recent version does.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of older versions of Spring Security had two settings, but I see your point about the wrapper the plugin provides.

Comment: I tried using the two properties above and it seems to make no difference. I still get redirected to the page requested, not the default. Which really doesn't make since I found in the docs for the plugin it words it such that it should work. http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/urlProperties.html

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out... the property should start with `grails.plugin` not `grails.plugins`. Once the extra 's' was removed it works like I was hoping.

Comment: Great! Updated the answer to reflect this as well. I need to remember that Burt changed that in 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I marked this as the accepted answer. Sometimes it is the simple things that cause the biggest headaches. :)

Comment: Great. I was skeptical about that change for config properties because I was thinking the change from `plugins` to `plugin` was done only for package names. Will update my answer as well. @Michael

Answer (score 8):

I am using grails 2.4.4 and it should be:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/your-url'
```

Instead of:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/your-url'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a setting [`successHandler.defaultTargetUrl`](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/urlProperties.html) (defaults to root context)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/home'
```

where `/home` represents route to home page.

Comment: This setting seems to have no effect on the behavior I see. If the session has expired the user is still redirected to the page they have clicked instead of the one specified in this property.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that `grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault` is set to `true` since you were redirecting on successful login earlier. @Michael